# Click On javascript or iframe adsvertisement to show button?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to when users is click on a Javascript or `iframe` ads then a next button will show

how can I do it?

this is the advertisement code:

````
<div id="adm-container-15022"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="//moonads.net/display/items.php?15022&647&728&90&4&0&0"></script> ```
````

Answer (score 1):

I have added the javascript function that should be executed when a person clicks on the div by using `onclick`. Then I had added a `button` and made its `display` equal to `none` so as to hide it. In the `function` definition, I selected the button using `document.querySelector` and then modified its `display` to `inline` to make it visible.

```
<div id="adm-container-15022" onclick="showButton()"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="//moonads.net/display/items.php?15022&647&728&90&4&0&0"></script>

<button id="NextButton" style="display: none;">Next</button>
<script>
function showButton()  {
    document.querySelector("#NextButton").style.display = "inline";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sir its also working on button but its not working on adsvertisement

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot by doing right click on the advertisement and then clicking on inspect.